# Multiple shipping costs in simpleCart

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplecart

First up, I should probably point out that I'm no JS expert and that I'm using simpleCart 2.2.2.

I'm hoping someone can help me with this script I found, which I'm trying to customise so that, based on the value of my select, the appropriate shipping cost is added to the cart. This kind of works, however, if you change the quantity in the cart the shipping cost doesn't increase accordingly. Also, if you add a combination of different items to the cart, the shipping doesn't display the cumulative shipping cost, just the cost for the item you added last.

There's probably a really neat way of doing this, but I'd appreciate any help!

Thanks

```
simpleCart.shipping = function(){
var shipping = 0,
extraShipping = document.getElementById( 'artSelect' ).value;

if( $("#artSelect").val() == "Original" ){
return 30;

} else if( $("#artSelect").val() == "Print" ){
shipping = 20;

} else if( $("#artSelect").val() == "Card" ){
shipping = 2;

} else {
shipping = 0;
} 

if( extraShipping === 'blank' ){
extraShipping = 0;
}

return shipping + extraShipping;

};
```